# What can I do to improve the following code so that the result is a single `TreeView.AddRange()`

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Just doing some final optimizations on my custom TreeView control, and it looks like I can optimize the load method a bit further.  Here is the segment I am focused on which I feel can be optimized by building all the TreeNodes first, and then using a single `TreeView.AddRange( nodes[] )` method.

```
// Create hierarchy and load into view
foreach (var id in _treeNodes.Keys)
{
    var node = GetNode(id);
    var obj = (T)node.Tag;
    var parentId = getParentId(obj);

    if (parentId.HasValue)
    {
        var parentNode = GetNode(parentId.Value);
        if(parentNode == null)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Nodes.Add(node)));

        } else
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => parentNode.Nodes.Add(node)));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Nodes.Add(node)));
    }
}
```

`_treeNodes` is `Dictionary<ulong, TreeNode>`

`GetNode()` is :

```
if(_treeNodes.ContainsKey(id))
{
    return _treeNodes[id];
} else
{
    return null;
}
```

`getParentId()` is a delegate `Func<NtfsUsnJournal.UsnEntry, ulong?> getParentId = (x => x.ParentFileReferenceNumber)`

The code currently gets all the values from a dictionary list which is all the directories in the NTFS Journal, which happens very fast. The delay is that on each `Node` and the children nodes, it is being added to the TreeView directly.

What I would like to do, is build a list of root Nodes (containing all child nodes of course), and then pass that as an array of `TreeNode[]` to the `.AddRange( TreeNode[] )` method in a single `Invoke()`.

How can this code be modified to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, answer was staring me in the face :

```
List<TreeNode> _t = new List<TreeNode>();
foreach (var id in _treeNodes.Keys)
{
    var node = GetNode(id);
    var obj = (T)node.Tag;
    var parentId = getParentId(obj);

    if (parentId.HasValue)
    {
        var parentNode = GetNode(parentId.Value);
        if(parentNode == null)
        {
            _t.Add(node);
        } else
        {
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _t.Add(node);
    }
}
Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Nodes.AddRange(_t.ToArray())));
```